# Link to Portfolio page by id instead of name

Tags: links

I'm trying to make a dynamic button that goes to portfolio page (no matter what ID/name it has), it's currently like this:

```
$portfolio_page = get_option('theme_portfolio_page');
$portfolio_pid = get_page_by_title($portfolio_page);

     <a href="<?php echo get_option ('theme_portfolio_page') ?>">Voltar</a>
```

The problem is that it links based on the page name, and when it has space on the name it bugs... So I would need a code that links dynamically to the portfolio page by ID

When I try to change to **get_page_by_id**

FATAL ERROR: CALL TO UNDEFINED FUNCTION GET_PAGE_BY_ID() IN /HOME/DOMAIN/WWW/WP-CONTENT/THEMES/MYTHEME/PORTFOLIO-TEMPLATE.PHP ON LINE 46

Comment: Whenever in doubt about a WordPress function, check the Codex, [**`get_page_by_title`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title), there you'd have found the correct function EAMann is referencing bellow. And checking the documentation of `get_page` will solve the doubt you are commenting about...

Answer (score 0):

That's because `get_page_by_id` isn't a function in WordPress.

You want [`get_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page).

Comment: When I try `get_page` or `get_page_link` instead of `get_page_by_title` it still links trough the title

Answer (score 0):

Try using Custom fields.

1.Add the page Id as a custom field value, for example "page_id".

add the following to your template file

```
$post = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'page_id', true );
```

Thus you will get the link of the page in $post

Then give this is in your anchor tag as href

```
<a href="<?php echo $post ?>" > Something</a>
```

Hope this solves your problem